# Google Maps API 10 Destinations only limitation

Tags: google-maps

I want to use google maps api for an assignment in my studies.

when entering the official google maps on chrome it seems like there's a destinations number limitation to 10 - so you can't create a route of more then 10 destinations.

Will that same limitation also be if i'll use the google maps API in my own project that I'm creating and not through the official website?

Answer (score 0):

Use a key.
Without a key, the limit is 8 waypoints.  With a (free) key, the limit is 23 waypoints (plus origin and destination).

From [the documentation (note that keys are now **required**, some sites are grandfathered with keyless access)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#waypoint-limits):

> **Limits and Restrictions for Waypoints**
>
> The following usage limits and restrictions apply:
>
> - The maximum number of waypoints allowed when using the Directions service in the Google Maps JavaScript API is 23, plus the origin and destination. The limits are the same for the Google Maps Directions API web service.
> - For the Google Maps Directions API web service, customers are allowed 23 waypoints, plus the origin, and destination.
> - Google Maps APIs Premium Plan customers are allowed 23 waypoints, plus the origin, and destination.